# Shift(Rota) Pattens Table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi all I was asked to create a employee table and that was fine works great.

```
SELECT ID,
   EmployeeNo,
   Surname,
   Forename,
   Team,
   BadgeNo,
   RotaType,
   StartDate,
   Flex,
   DaliyHours,
   CurrentTask,
   LastUpdated,
   LastUpdated_By
FROM CHDS_Sandbox.dbo.emp_PeopleDHL;
```

I noticed they had RotaType and asked why.

Well I wish I did not they have 56 different rotas and want as way for staff to be able to scan the barcode on their badge an it tell them what shifts they are working for the next 7 days or month.

So do I set up 56 different tables for each rota or is there a way I can set up on table and run a query that will look up the date then a the RotaType and feed out the time they are due to start?

Comment: Your question is very vague - please keep in mind that we cannot see your screen, and have no idea what a `Rota` is.  But, to answer your first question: do not create 56 tables...  Create a table just for the rotas, and add a foreign key to your DHL table that references it.  You might also want to look into `JOIN` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks Siyual (Rota is a timetable of work)
The first plan was to have a column for each rota and a row for each day. Then where the RotaType and say today cross each other this would be the time they start today.

Comment: First you need to figure out, in detail, what a _rota_ entails. Perhaps a `RotaId`, `BaseDate` (the date the cycle starts, just to keep everyone in sync), `DayNumber` (offset into the cycle), `ShiftNumber` (assuming there are common shifts). Shifts would be defined in another table, e.g. `ShiftId`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`. (The fun part is handling shifts that span midnight, i.e. `StartTime` > `EndTime`.) What does it mean to change a shift or rota, e.g. does it apply to everyone at once or only at the start of the next day/month/cycle/lunar cycle? ...

Answer (score 0):

A single table should be fine.

```
create table RotaInfo (id INT identity (1,1),
                       RotaType INT, --should match the existing RotaType, this will be your FK
                       RotaName varchar(50),
                       DayOfMonth INT,
                       StartTime TIME,
                       EndTime TIME);
```

You can then use a calendar CTE to get the start/end times for any given day for any given employee.

Comment: I think you might have it here I am going to go with this for a bit see if I can get it to work.